# RecyclerView expand text button

Tags: android, button, textview, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerView` with `CardViews` and `TextView` with 10+ lines. How can I show only 4 lines and button which will expand `TextView` when is clicked.

I want to create something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9HCB.png)

Comment: I will try to do something for you.

Comment: @GIGAMOLE, thank you. Will wait for your reply. I have been searching for solution for 3 days, but found nothing.

Comment: @GIGAMOLE, have you any news?